# IdentityServer4 won't return token - 404 not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have implemented IdentityServer4 in my project. After I run it and use Postman to send a request for token I get 404 status code for not found, even though URL exists.

I want to use Implicit grant_type so I am sending only client_id using Basic Auth.

Problem can also be related to the format of request for implicit flow of OAuth 2. As I've understood the only thing you need to pass when you using this flow is client_id and use Basic authentication. Maybe I am wrong about that one?

[image]

In VisualStudio I can see that request are coming to IdentityServer

[image]

Even if I go to see debug message I don't see what kind of error is returning 404, all I got is this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44305/baseurl/connect/token  0
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2017-01-06T11:02:42.0216819Z","tags":{"ai.device.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-3TKHRTV","ai.operation.id":"p4f7oSz6Ng0=","ai.user.userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36","ai.operation.name":"POST /baseurl/connect/token","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:1.0.0"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"p4f7oSz6Ng0=","name":"POST /baseurl/connect/token","startTime":"2017-01-06T11:02:42.0216819+00:00","duration":"00:00:00.0028138","success":false,"responseCode":"404","url":"https://localhost:44305/baseurl/connect/token","httpMethod":"POST","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 48.134ms 404
```

Code for IdentityServer is pretty straightforward and standard:

```
public class Startup
{
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment environment;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            environment = env;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "idsvr3test.pfx"), "idsrv3test");

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(ClientConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(ClientConfig.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(ClientConfig.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryUsers(ClientConfig.GetUsers());
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
}

public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
 }

public class ClientConfig
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mob.client",
                ClientName = "Mobile client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44311/Unauthorized" },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("MyLegislatureAPI", "BEE MyLegislature API")
        };
    }

    public static List<InMemoryUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<InMemoryUser>
        {
            new InMemoryUser{Subject = "818727", Username = "alice", Password = "alice",
                Claims = new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Alice Smith"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Alice"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "AliceSmith@email.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Geek"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.WebSite, "http://alice.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Address, @"{ 'street_address': 'One Hacker Way', 'locality': 'Heidelberg', 'postal_code': 69118, 'country': 'Germany' }", IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json)
                }
            },
            new InMemoryUser{Subject = "88421113", Username = "bob", Password = "bob",
                Claims = new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Bob Smith"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Bob"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "BobSmith@email.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Developer"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Geek"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.WebSite, "http://bob.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Address, @"{ 'street_address': 'One Hacker Way', 'locality': 'Heidelberg', 'postal_code': 69118, 'country': 'Germany' }", IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json)
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Does anyone sees what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: Try Post using   ‘x-www-form-urlencoded’ selected under Body. Provide two key/values for the form 'username' and ‘password’

Comment: Do you want to use basic Authentication?

Answer (score 10):

What you're missing here is the part where you inject the Identity Server middleware in the pipeline. At the moment, all you're doing is registering the necessary services in the DI container.

In your `Configure` method, you need to call `app.UseIdentityServer` at some point.

Please have a look at the [amazing documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html#basic-setup) the core developers put together.

Comment: Thanks for answering. After adding missing call to a middleware I am still getting 404 Not found. But I will check out this great documentation you have provided me. Funny thing is that my colleague can normally run it and gets token when using Postman on his machine for the same code. Not sure if there can be something related to machine configuration or settings... It shouldn't be, at least I think...@MickaëlDerriey

Comment: @nemo_87 You're right, it shouldn't. Are you and your colleague running the exact same code? Maybe you have differences in the order of middlewares or something else?

Comment: Code is totally same. We use git, so in any given moment we have same code for IS4. We even did same settings, installing certificates in a same way, etc. When I run it in a debug mode, using IISExpress, as you can see server is up and running, it receives calls from postman, but it looks like the calls are not in correct format, which is weird as well, since I am sending request in a same manner as others do... :/ @MickaëlDerriey

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey broken link

Answer (score 7):

Check your IdentityServer project URL.

I see you have "baseurl" as part of your path.

mine is: `http://localhost:5000/connect/token`.

To help you verify check your configuration URL to make sure that works.

mine is: `http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration`.